# Boolean function in C

Tags: c, linux, function, error-handling, boolean

what I'm trying to do is see if a year is bissextile or not,
but when I'm using a boolean function it gives me this strange message.

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

main(){
    int n1;
    printf("what is the year?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n1);

    if(itIS(n1)){
        printf("the year %d is bissextile\n",n1);
    }else{
        printf("the year %d is not bissextile\n",n1);
    }
}

bool itIS(int n1){
    bool is = false;
    if((n1/400)== 0){
        is = true;
    }
    return is;
}
```

and this is the thing that appears to me:

```
  exe1.c:144:6: error: conflicting types for ‘itIS’ bool itIS(int n1){
  ^
  exe1.c:134:6: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘itIS’ was here if(itIS(n1)==true){
  ^
```

I don't understand what's the problem. Although if I do this without the boolean function it works perfectly.

Edit: So i already know what's the problem thanks to @Bill Lynch. 
      The problem is i need to write the boolean function before the main function, so the compiler sees the function, basically that's it.

Comment: the main function is written as 'int main(void)'  or 'int main( int argc, char **argv ).   enable all warnings when compiling, then your compiler would have told you about this problem (and about the missing return value; statement at the end of main()

Comment: the code is missing, before main() a prototype for function: 'bool itIS( int );'

Comment: @user3629249 even when adding 'int main(void)' it gives the same warning :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare the function before using it. Add this before `main`:

```
 bool itIS(int n1);
```

Also, it's `int main(void)`, not `main()`

Comment: it runs just fine like this,by default already does that. but is it really bad writing like this ?!

Comment: @bluewolfxD If you mean `int main`, yes, you must write it with return type of `int`.